# Идеологически правильная работа с WCF-службой через WinForms приложение?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

Подскажите, а как идеологически правильно работают с WCF-службой в `WinForms` приложении?

Текущая моя реализация в различных участках кода создает посредника.
Т.е, надо клиенту получить данные о продажах, вызывается метод, а в этом методе создается посредник, который дергает пару методов WCF-службы и посредник уничтожается.

На сколько это верно?

Или правильнее иметь в главной форме свойство с типом посредника и инициализировать его при создании формы, а потом передавать его в качестве аргументов в конструкторы других форм?

Или есть более красивые варианты?

**UPD:**

И еще вопрос:

Допустим, служба имеет несколько конечных точек.

Соответственно, на стороне клиента под каждую точку нужен свой прокси.

Как обуздать этот зоопарк на стороне клиента? Правильно ли будет создать на стороне клиента класс, который будет внутри себя хранить все прокси или есть что-то красивее?

Comment: Не-не-не, никакого модельного кода в формах. Разделите код на модель, представление, и уровень между ними (контроллер, view model, presenter, что вам нравится больше).

Comment: Работа с WCF-сервисом не должна зависеть от времени жизни окна.

Comment: Какой транспорт вы используете?

Comment: @VladD насколько я понял его объяснения, у него и не зависит...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я имел в виду часть «Или правильнее иметь в главной форме свойство с типом посреднка и инициализировать его при создании формы». Сервис имеет право работать и до создания формы.

Comment: @VladD а сервис у меня хостится на вин сервисе . По идее служба в любом случае будет работать. А можно примерчик проекта с правильной реализацией. Сценарий такой главная форма создает новую форму, а новая формат шлет запрос к службе

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ох. Маленьких примерчиков правильно структурированных приложений, боюсь, не бывает. Смысл в том, что у вас есть часть, заведующая логикой приложения (обычно называется «бизнес-логикой»), и она командует всем: тем, что запускается соединение с WCF-сервисом, и тем, что начинает отображаться форма. То есть, не форма шлёт запрос, а бизнес-логика шлёт запрос (прямо или косвенно, через модель), и отображает результат на форме. Форма должна заниматься **только** отображением.

Comment: @VladD без реального примера тяжело такое понять, как это выглядит. Неужели нельзя показать правильную структуру в WinForms проекте, где 2 формы. Необязательно даже делать рабочую WCF службу.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Я работал только с WPF, и не знаю, как полагается делать в WinForms. Попробую спросить в чате, может быть, у кого-то есть пример.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать DI контейнер куда зарегистрировать класс для работы c WCF сервисом  и делать запросы уже через него. В созданном классе инкапсулируешь логику работы с WCF сервисом а также можно кешировать некоторые запросы.

1. Для начала определим интерфейс работы с wcf службой. С примеру это будет получить список студентов, групп, преподавателей.

   ```
   public interface IUniverDataService
   {
       IEnumerable<Student> Students {get;} 
       IEnumerable<StudGroup> StudGroups {get;}
       //и т.д.
   }
   ```
2. Наследуем интерфейс и реализуем класс работы с wcf сервисом

   ```
   WcfUniverDataService : IUniverDataService
   {
       //реализуем интерфейс для работы с WCF сервисом
   }
   ```
3. После регистрации класса в контейнере, мы можем использовать объект класса WcfUniverDataService в необходимом нам классе указав его интерфейс в конструкторе

   ```
   public class SomeClass
   {
       IUniverDataService _univerDataService;
        public SomeClass(IUniverDataService univerDataService)
        {
             _univerDataService = univerDataService;
             //используем наш класс работы с wcf сервисом в это классе.
        }
   }
   ```
4. Но для того что бы использовать создать DI контейнер и зарегистрировть там класс.
   DI контейнеры бывают разные для примера возьмём Unity. Его можно найти в NuGet.

Создаём контейнер, в вашем случае в главной форме

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
```

В контейнере регистрируем ранее созданный класс

```
container.RegisterType<IUniverDataService,WcfUniverDataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: А пример можно?

Comment: Что бы лишнего не писать, пару вопросов. Знаком с IoC Di контейнерами?

Comment: ,нет, не знаком

Comment: отредактировал ответ, с пояснениями.